# История развития .NET и frameworks (mvc, core etc)

Tags: .net, asp.net, framework, .net-core, история

Хочу изучать бэкэнд. Не могу разобраться с кто есть кто. На просторах инета увидел кучу разных названий, куча уроков, но почти никто не поясняет историю создания и что актуально в данный момент. ASP.NET, ASP.NET CORE, ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET FRAMEWORK и еще с десяток аббревиатур в которых эти слова переставлены местами. Помогите внести ясность. Если я правильно понял, то вначале был ASP.NET, после вышла новая версия ASP.NET CORE. Дальше непонятно.

Comment: Вначале посмотрите чем отличается .NET Framework и .NET Core.

Comment: Насколько я понял первым был .NET Framework. Сделан исключительно под винду и на нем можно было создавать MVC, Winforms, WPF. После сделали 
.NET CORE - кроссплатформенный фрэймворк и осталась возможность создавать только MVC.

Выходит так: .NET FRAMEWORK -> .NET CORE. MVC - шаблон для построения приложения (есть и в .NET FRAMEWORK и в .NET CORE). Во всем этом ASP это
технология по которой создаются вэб страницы на стороне сервера. ASP.NET та же технология, но основанная на .NET FRAMEWORK.

Попровьте или дополните.

Comment: Не совсем. .NET Core может использоваться для создания консольных приложений, MVC, WEB API. Также есть opensource фреймворк Avalonia UI для создания интерфейсов.

Answer (score 1):

Да, MS немного запутал с Core-названиями.

.NET Framework - это Windows-специфичный фреймворк. Он рабоает только под Windows. В нем много функционала, завязанного именно именно на WinAPI.

Параллельно с ним разрабатывается кроссплатформенный .NET Core. В чем-то он опережает .NET Framework, в чем-то - отстает. Это не замена .NET Framework, и не "следующая версия". Какие-то фичи из .NET Framework в .NET Core никогда не появятся.

Общее подмножество фич .NET Framework и .NET Core называется .NET Standard. Код, написанный под .NET Standard можно запускать как на платформе .NET Framework, так и на .NET Core.

---

ASP.NET Core - это идейный наследник ASP.NET (включая, но не ограничиваясь ASP.NET MVC). По сути, это написанный с почти с нуля фреймворк для веб разработки, достаточно сильно обратно совместимый по коду с ASP.NET MVC 5 / ASP.NET WebAPI.

Несмотря на идейное наследие и относительную совместимость - это *новый* фреймворк, который можно использовать как под .NET Framework (не Core), так и под .NET Core, а не просто "новая версия".

Нельзя просто взять приложение на ASP.NET MVC 5 и "обновить версию" - придется мигрировать часть кода вручную.

Т.е. Core в ASP.NET Core имеет очень слабое отношение к Core в .NET Core. Это просто отметка нового подхода.

---

Хотите изучать бэкенд - изучайте ASP.NET Core, под .NET Framework / .NET Core на ваш выбор.